# Can I use CORS to restrict both domain and subfolder in that domain?

Tags: apache, http, cors, apache2

I would like to restrict, for example, requests that come only from:
`box.com/my.point` vs entire of `box.com`
Is there a way with CORS to also control subfolder origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, `Origin` does [not contain the path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7).

You can implement a proprietary solution based on `Referer` header, but it might not be respected by all the clients as it will be proprietary. (Check `Referer` and reply the CORS headers only if it matches your path.)